# Can I load a SpriteFont without a content project?

Tags: xna

I'm developing a game in XNA, however, I do not want to use a content project. I'm loading all my textures through different means, and I'd also like to load my fonts without a content project.

Is there any quick way to maybe include the `SpriteFont` in the main game project?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isnt a quick way to load a font as a sprite font. As todo that a font is baked into a texture. Maybe head over to MonoGame and check their source code to see if they have something for text rendering. Why are you not using the content project btw? Its a good way to pack and manage textures.

Comment: A content project isn't ideal for my needs, because all the textures I use are concentrated in two different very large spritesheets. I want to be able to change these files out very easily, and I want to use my own code to load and process them.

Comment: That is what custom content importers and processors are for :)

Answer (score 1):

XNA is designed around the content processor pipeline and `SpriteFont` resources are designed to make use of that. There are really no *good* ways to circumvent that.

You *could* create a separate project that used a content project to generate and load the sprite font, and then use reflection to access the `SpriteFont` object's private members, including `textureValue` (which is a `Texture2D`) and spit them out to some format you can parse yourself. But that is really a bit heavy-handed, and at that point not much different than using a third-party, API-agnostic bitmap font generation tool (like [BMFont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/)).

Plus it still uses a content project somewhere in your pipeline. Your best option if you really don't want to make use of XNA's content pipeline is to find third-party tools.